# Posting a form with jQuery and want to change the submit button after click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Posting a form with jQuery and want to change the submit button after click.

Here's the code I'm using :P but did not work!

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").click(function(){

 $("#button").submit(sendForm)
});

function sendForm() {

    $.post('post.cfm',$("#button").serialize(),function(data,status){

        $("#result").html(data)
    });

    return false
}

$("#button").html("Friend request sent");

  });

});

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="button">
<input type="submit" value="Add as a friend">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // #button is your form's id, it's confusing
    $('#button').on('submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this);
        $.post('post.cfm', form.serialize(), function(data){
            $("#result").html(data);
            form.find(':submit').val("Friend request sent");
        });
    });
});
```

Also, add some inputs (text boxes as form data to post) in the form and give your submit button a `name/id` (better) and yes, you asked what the hell that message was, it was because you didn't provide enough information but only some code so, `StackOverflow` asked to provide more information so anyone could have understood the problem and as a result you would be benefited. Anyways, read the [documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) properly, you need to learn the basic first and this is not a tutorial site.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
var sendForm = function() {

    $.post('post.cfm',$("#button").serialize(),function(data,status){

        $("#result").html(data)
    });

    var request = $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        dataType:'json',
        url:'post.cfm',
        data:{
            data: $('#button').val()
        },
        success:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            // Do something
        },
        error:function(data){
            console.log(data);
            // Do something
        }
    });
    request.done(function(data){
        alert("Friend request sent");
    });

    return false;
}

$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#button").click(function(){

 $("#button").submit(sendForm)
});
```